# Selenium mocha Tests

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I was trying to put an implicit wait in selenium java script with mocha but i see the following error:

> ReferenceError: timeUnit is not defined

Below is the code snippet i used:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, timeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and the stack trace I see is:

```
at Context.<anonymous> (C:\node_modules\Script\login_scenario.js:32:50)
at C:\node_modules\Script\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\testing\index.js:142:19
at new promise.Promise (C:\node_modules\Script\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:355:5)
at controlFlowExecute (C:\node_modules\Script\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\testing\index.js:127:14)
at promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\node_modules\Script\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20)
at promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\node_modules\Script\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1755:8
at null.<anonymous> (C:\node_modules\Script\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12)
at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\node_modules\Script\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
: Task: Automation of Shop Management Login scenario
at Context.ret (C:\node_modules\Script\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\testing\index.js:126:10)
at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\kashyap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:233:15)
at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\kashyap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:387:10)
at C:\Users\kashyap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:470:12
at next (C:\Users\kashyap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:312:14)
at C:\Users\kashyap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:322:7
at next (C:\Users\kashyap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:257:23)
at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\kashyap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:289:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`implicitlyWait()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver_Timeouts.html) in *javascript selenium bindings* accepts a **single argument** - a timeout in `milliseconds`:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20000);
```

---

You are probably mixing it up with [`implicitlyWait()` method from *java selenium bindings*](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), which allows you to specify the timeout unit alongside with the timeout itself.